# EF Core Add-Migration error property already exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I'm trying to create another migration, and I don't understand why I keep having this error. Why does it even try to add the property again? I added it on the previous migration, now database is up to date, and I want to add other changes. What am I doing wrong?

```
PM> Add-Migration Northwind1.3
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: The property or navigation 'EmployeeRole' cannot be added to the entity type 'AdoNet.Entities.EF.Employee' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'AdoNet.Entities.EF.Employee'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.AddNavigation(MemberIdentity navigationMember, ForeignKey foreignKey, Boolean pointsToPrincipal)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.AddNavigation(String name, ForeignKey foreignKey, Boolean pointsToPrincipal)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ForeignKey.Navigation(Nullable`1 propertyIdentity, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean pointsToPrincipal)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ForeignKey.SetDependentToPrincipal(String name, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalForeignKeyBuilder.HasNavigations(Nullable`1 navigationToPrincipal, Nullable`1 navigationToDependent, EntityType principalEntityType, EntityType dependentEntityType, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalForeignKeyBuilder.HasNavigations(Nullable`1 navigationToPrincipal, Nullable`1 navigationToDependent, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalForeignKeyBuilder.HasNavigation(String name, Boolean pointsToPrincipal, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType, Nullable`1 navigationToTarget, Nullable`1 inverseNavigation, Nullable`1 setTargetAsPrincipal, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 required)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType, String navigationName, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 targetIsPrincipal)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder.HasOneBuilder(MemberIdentity navigationId, EntityType relatedEntityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder.HasOne(String relatedTypeName, String navigationName)
   at AdoNet.Migrations.NorthwindContextModelSnapshot.<>c.<BuildModel>b__0_31(EntityTypeBuilder b) in D:\Programming\Csharp\epam-inner\homework\adonet\AdoNet\Migrations\NorthwindContextModelSnapshot.cs:line 1086
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(String name, Action`1 buildAction)
   at AdoNet.Migrations.NorthwindContextModelSnapshot.BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in D:\Programming\Csharp\epam-inner\homework\adonet\AdoNet\Migrations\NorthwindContextModelSnapshot.cs:line 1084
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSnapshot.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSnapshot.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The property or navigation 'EmployeeRole' cannot be added to the entity type 'AdoNet.Entities.EF.Employee' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'AdoNet.Entities.EF.Employee'.
```

Employee:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeTerritories = new HashSet<EmployeeTerritory>();
        InverseReportsToNavigation = new HashSet<Employee>();
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int? ReportsTo { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeRoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployeeRole EmployeeRole { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee ReportsToNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeTerritory> EmployeeTerritories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> InverseReportsToNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

EmployeeRole:

```
public partial class EmployeeRole
{
    public EmployeeRole()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int EmployeeRoleId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeRoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

From the modelBuilder of Employee in NorthwindContext:

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.EmployeeRole)
    .WithMany(p => p.Employees)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeRoleId);
```

Also the EmployeeRoleId property in EmployeeRole is faded for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think the _MigrationHistory tables in Database are not updated. Check the _MigrationHistory for the last migration applied in this table

Comment: I have 2 previous migrations and they are both in the __EFMigrationsHistory table.

Comment: First check the relationship of the database table and make sure it is correct. Then, if not ok, change the name of the navigation or property ( EmployeeRole virtual public EmployeeRole {get; set;} to EmployeeRole virtual public EmployeeRole _test {get; set;;

Comment: Everything is correct in the database too

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If you lack the rep to comment(50) avoid posting answers that should be comments, as any downvotes thy acquire actively detract from gaining the rep needed to comment